# What do these two "which"s refer to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, clauses

> Superstition, Flusfeder argues, isn’t some primitive hangover from our distant past. It is the inevitable result of our capacity for taking mental shortcuts, **which** makes us capable of thinking on our feet, and without **which** we wouldn’t be able to function at all.

Do the two "which"s refer to "superstition", or "result", or "capacity" or "mental shortcuts"?

Comment: Both are relative pronouns, which must refer to noun phrases (not just to single nouns). The first _which_ refers to the NP _our capacity for taking mental shortcuts_, which is the object of _of_ in the NP _the result of_. The second one also refers to the same noun phrase because of the _and_, which connects the parallel clauses. The _without_ in front of the second _which_ is the result of Pied Piping but doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JohnLawler What are "single nouns"? I thought you were contrasting them with noun phrases, but in your comment, doesn't "which" refer to "relative pronouns"? (Is "relative pronouns" a "single noun"?)

Comment: If a noun phrase has a head noun, then many people have been taught that relative pronouns refer to that noun. But quite often the noun phrase a relative modifies is an entire clause, which doesn't have a head noun, or the entire NP itself, rather than a part of it. So it's not really correct to say the relative pronouns above refer to a single word; rather they refer to the entire NP it's in. It's a general rule that accounts for more than single words here and there -- constituents are the important parts of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

*Which* must refer to *capacity.*

*Superstition* isn't even in the same sentence, and *mental shortcuts* is plural so it would have to be *which make.* It doesn't make much sense for *which* to refer to *result.*